# Difference between classed() and attr("class")

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js

I have been using these two interchangeably, so I decided to switch over to just one. When I tried to do this, I ran into some odd behavior. What are the differences between using `.classed("className", bool)` and `.attr("class", "className")`?

Comment: What is the "odd" behavior? Maybe that would answer your question on what is different. :)

Comment: Oof, I will try to come up with a concise explanation but my code is honestly a bit of a mess. I was also just curious in general, because I always assumed these would be equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.classed("name", bool)
```

Adds or removes the class provided. It leaves all other classes applied in tact. So `<div class="foo bar" >`would be `<div class="foo bar className" >` after calling it with .classed w/ true.

```
.attr("class", "className")
```

Will wipe out all of the classes applied to that element and add only that one class name. So `<div class="foo bar" >`would be `<div class="className" >` after calling it with attr.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot to me. I didn't realize that would be the case, so now I'll be more careful about it. One more thing, is it an okay coding practice to use both in different situations?

Comment: Although to be fair, using `.attr("class", "className1 className2")` will apply both class names -- not just one. The key difference is that `attr` will actually replace the full `class` attribute. :)

Comment: I think it's ok to use `attr('class', 'className')` when you have control over the elements (you create, modify and remove them). If you are assigning classes to objects that could be modifyied or styled by others, I prefer to add classes using `classed('className', true)`.

Comment: Note that `classed('className')` will return `true` or `false`, so if you forget adding the boolean argument it won't add the class, and it might cause problems later.

Comment: @CaseyFalk Well, I tried using `addClass("className")` and `removeClass("className")`, but I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Is there something about the syntax I'm not understanding?

Comment: @CaseyFalk Ah I see, I'm not using jQuery at this point so that explains that

Comment: Oh dear -- you're right. I read the title, assumed you were using it, and didn't regard the tags. Silly D3 and it's jQuery-like names lol. My apologies for the confusion! I'll delete those comments now to help others in the future, haha. Thanks for catching that @Null-Username.

Comment: @CaseyFalk Why don't you just edit your comment to mention that you need jQuery for those methods? That way someone using d3 and jQuery might learn of it

Comment: After a certain time period you can't edit comments anymore. :'( Plus, I'm sure there is a detailed SO post regarding how to manipulate classes in jQuery; there is more jQuery stuff that flows through SO than D3.js, haha. :)